# Where can I find my "face code"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

From what I understand, when you're editing your appearance at the beginning of the game, at the bottom of the screen a "face code" is generated. This "face code" consists of a string of text that represents the details of your character's face. For example, this one possible face code:

> 141.111.WW1.Q7Q.CAE.34M.9L5.711.QN8.B13.B4B.17A

The above face code represents the following face:

[image]

This is an extremely convenient way to share your character's appearance with people, but it's not so convenient to access. For all I know, the only time you can access this face code is during the appearance editing process. If you wanted to share your face with  someone after leaving that interface, there is no way to do so. But this is all, again, "for all I know"...

**Is there a way to access your face code after leaving the appearance editing interface at the beginning of the game?**

*(Note: Credit goes to [these guys at the Bioware forum](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/323/index/9656899) for introducing me to the face code.)*

Comment: I know on Xbox it showed up on my squad screen...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open your "Squad" menu, the identity code is displayed in the top left hand corner of the screen.

[image]

Comment: What a goodie goodie two-shoes

Comment: @Farseeker 5+ years and counting!

Comment: How nice of EA to not let you copy the text. What idiots.

Answer (score 3):

With [Gibbed's ME3 Save Editor](http://svn.gib.me/builds/masseffect3/), you can read the Face Code from a save file without launching the game. The code is under Squad -> Player.
[image]